# How To Check If Node EsModule Was Imported Or Ran Directly

Tags: node.js, command-line, es6-modules, mjs

Node.js 13 recently rolled out an experimental ESModule loader, starting to take the switch away from CommonJS. However, code ran in an ESModule in Node.js isn't provided a `require` function, instead requiring the use of the new `import` syntax.

My problem is that typically the way to find out if a module was loaded via an import or ran directly from the command line requires the `require` function to be provided, because it check's `require`'s `main` property against the current module's `module` object. Since `require` isn't provided in an ESModule in Node.js, how do I check if my ESModule was imported or ran directly from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

given that you have "some function" that you want to export *or* run if your module is invoked directly, via `node my-script.js`,

```js
// my-script.js
export async function myTask() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

You can run `myTask` via adding:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)

// existing
export async function myTask() {
  console.log('hi');
}
// end existing

let entryFile = process.argv?.[1];

if (entryFile === __filename) {
  myTask();
}
```

this way, other scripts can

```js
import { myTask } from './my-script.js';
```

without invoking `myTask` immediately, as you'd want when invoking from the CLI with `node`